# DIY table saw reusing components from other table saws

Tags: table, saw

I would like to know what are the major obstacles if I try to build a new table saw. My major problem today is that my DeWalt 745 has an aluminium top. I was wondering if I stand any chance to move the motor to a cast iron top that from another table saw (I just saw one for sale on ebay from a Rigid 4512)

Comment: Moving just a motor isn't a major task, assuming similar output shafts. If the replacement motor is from a direct-drive saw it may be more difficult, and you may not have much luck with compatibility of accessories.

Comment: Swapping out a drive motor on a belt driven table saw is hardly rebuilding it.  Any motor with a shiv and proper mounting detail will drive a blade.  Confirm the right rotation and make sure the motor is operating within its amperage limits.  A 10" blade will require a horse to a horse and half motor.

Comment: DeWalt 745 is direct drive, no belt there
I guess there might be some challenges regarding how the motor is attached to the top

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the guts of the Ridgid saw, but I can imagine that a switcheroo isn't going to be simple. (Probably not impossible, just not simple.)

However, I have to question your motivations.

- size of top? Simple -- just build a big table that you can drop the dewalt into
- fence capacity? Not quite as simple, but not impossible to put a new Biesemeyer-type fence and rail on a table. (Spendy, though, if you buy new...)
- mass? I know the dewalt is light and thus squirrely, but there are a number of ways of weighing it down. If you tend you use it in a table, then bolt it on and weight the table legs. If it's on the ground, you can bolt it to a long hunk of ply (which will also help with tipping).

Last but not least, the dewalt has value if you were to sell it. If you really want something more substantial, you might just sell it and buy what you want.

Comment: I am seeing Deltas for sale for 50-100-200 CAD depending on the age and condition. 
T-tracks is one reason why I want a different table top
The current top scratches very easy (the crosscut that I build is already leaving marks on it)

Comment: UHMW tape ("slick tape") might help in the near term with the scratching/gouging. Fair point about the t-tracks.